# How to display the names of documents (PDF) in a TermDocumentmatrix

Tags: r, pdf

When inspecting my termdocumentmatrix, the Column headers are displayed as numbers instead of the file names (of the PDF's).

```
          Docs
Terms      **10 11 2 3  4 5 6 7 8  9**
  abil      1  2 0 0  0 0 0 0 0  1
  abl       0  1 0 0  6 0 1 0 0  0
  access    4  6 0 0  3 0 0 0 0  1
  accord    0  2 1 0  2 0 0 0 0  2
  account   3  2 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  1
  activ     5 18 2 5 14 1 3 2 2 10
  addit     3  1 2 0  0 1 2 0 3  2
  address   1  1 2 1  0 0 0 0 2  3
  adequ     0  2 0 0  2 2 0 0 0  1
  adequaci  1  0 0 0  1 1 0 0 2  2
```

These are my steps so far:

```
setwd("E:/OneDrive/Thesis/Received comments document/Consultation 14")
getwd()
library(pdftools)
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
comments <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(comments))
Comments.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
    stopwords = TRUE,
    tolower = TRUE,
    stemming = TRUE,
    removeNumbers = TRUE,
bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf)))`) 

inspect(Comments.tdm[1:11,])
```

I have tried to remedy this by using:

```
meta(corp[[1]], tag = "id") <- files[1]
```

which returns the error message:

```
**Error in `[.data.frame`(x$dmeta, tag) : undefined columns selected**
```

How do i make sure the column headers display the file names of the PDF's?

Comment: Maybe `corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(comments));names(corp) <- files`?

Comment: Instant win! That did the job instantly. Thanks for the very quick response

Comment: Good and simple solution, which still works after three plus years :)  Thank you @lukeA